# Which Controller to Use?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp

This is a "MVC best practices" question. I have a User model with a belongs to relationship with Child. I want to display a list of children for a specific user. I could access all children related to a single user through the view action within the users controller, or I could access them through an action in the children controller with a where clause with the user_id. Which would be the best practice? Handing things like this in the parent (users) controller? Or handling this in the children controller?

Answer (score 2):

Since it has to do with a specific User but not a specific Child, I'd say it would be good to put it in the users controller as an action called *children*.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine in my opinion. The most important thing is to be consistent.